# Using cp -av command showing destination folder as not a directory. Please help in solving it

Tags: command-line, 16.04, copy

I am trying to copy and replace a file from my desktop to usr /local/matlab/r2016a/bin folder. It already has a file with the same name. Any help to solve this problem would be appreciated!

```
User@Try:~/Desktop/R2016a/Matlab R2016a$ sudo cp -av libcufft.so.7.5.18 libmwservices.so usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/
[sudo] password for User: 
cp: target 'usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/' is not a directory
```

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the leading `/`, try:

```
sudo cp -av libcufft.so.7.5.18 libmwservices.so /usr/local/MATLAB/R2016a/bin/
```